# Combining multiple categories based on URL segments

Tags: categories

I have two category groups - brands and resources. Under these I have product videos and documentation entries - section ‘resources’. I’m using the brands categories elsewhere for products too so I’ve taken care to use .section(‘resources').

I have three templates - a landing page (all good), a category page (all good) which shows the resources categories entries and filtered by the resources categories fine. This is the URL structure

http://kelairpumps-craft.local/resources/product-videos

[image]

I have a further ‘brands’ template which I’m trying to combine the two categories for - URL structure:

http://kelairpumps-craft.local/resources/product-videos/atlas

I’ve succeeded in filtering the entries fine but cant for some reason get the ‘brands’ nav to work properly. Whatever I do it's showing either nothing under brands or all of the brands categories with entries when I need it to show for example product-videos + brand.

The problem I have is that it is showing the Corken brand category when the product-videos and a brand category are selected which it shouldn’t because there are no product videos for Corken. I’ve only added Corken under Operating manuals.

[image]

[image][image]
I created this route:-
I’m just not grokking the source/target/element part of the relatedTo equation.

The ‘brands’ template follows which is show for the third segment situation. Please tell me what I’m doing wrong here…

```
{# get categories from url segments #}
{% set resourceSlug = craft.app.request.segment(2) %}
{% set brandSlug = craft.app.request.segment(3) %}

{# match current categories #}
{% set currentCategory1 = craft.categories.group('resources').slug(resourceSlug).one() %}
{% set currentCategory2 = craft.categories.group('brands').slug(brandSlug).one() %}


<div class="body-copy">

    <header class="inset">
        <h1>{{ currentCategory1 }} - {{ currentCategory2 }}</h1>
    </header>

    {% paginate craft.entries.relatedTo(['and',
        { targetElement: currentCategory1.id, field: 'resourceCategories' },
        { targetElement: currentCategory2.id, field: 'brands' }
    ]).limit('12').orderBy('title') as pageInfo, catentries %}

    <ul class="hlisting">
        {% for entry in catentries %}
            <li class="entry clearfix">

                {% set teaserimage = entry.resourceImage.one() %}
                {% if teaserimage %}
                    <div class="img-container vid-thumb">
                        <a class="image" href="{{ entry.url }}">
                            <img class="border" alt="{{ teaserimage.title }}" srcset="{{ teaserimage.getUrl('smallListingThumb') }}" src="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                <h2 class="">
                    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
                </h2>

                {{ entry.resourceSummary }}

            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% if pageInfo.totalPages > 1 %}
        {% include '_includes/pagination' %}
    {% endif %}

</div>


<aside class="secondary-copy">
    <div class="gutter">

        <h2 class="h4"><a href="/resources">Resources</a></h2>

        {# Resource Categories Global Query #}
        {# Grab all entry ID's from Resources #}
        {% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('resources').ids() %}

        {# Create a category query with the resources 'group' parameter #}
        {% set myCategoryQuery = craft.categories().group('resources') %}

        {# match current category for active class #}
        {% set categorySlug = craft.app.request.segment(2) %}
        {% set currentCategory = craft.categories.group('resources').slug(categorySlug).one() %}

        {# Fetch the categories - only return categories that have a relationship with one of our entry ids #}
        {% set categories = myCategoryQuery.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).all() %}

        {# Create a category query with the brands 'group' parameter #}
        {% set myBrandCategoryQuery = craft.categories().group('brands') %}

        {# match current brands category for active class #}
        {% set brandsCategorySlug = craft.app.request.segment(3) %}
        {% set currentBrandCategory = craft.categories.group('brands').slug(brandsCategorySlug).one() %}

        {# Fetch the categories - only return categories that have a relationship with one of our entry ids #}
        {% set brandCategories = myBrandCategoryQuery.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).all() %}

        {# Display the navigation #}
        <ul class="section_nav">
            {% nav category in categories %}
                {% set activeClass = category.id == currentCategory.id ? 'selected' %}
                <li{% if activeClass %} class="{{ activeClass }}"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endnav %}
        </ul>

        {# Display the brand navigation #}
        <h2 class="h4">
            <a href="/brands">By Brand</a>
        </h2>

        <ul class="section_nav">
            {% nav category in brandCategories %}
                {% set activeClass = category.id == currentBrandCategory.id ? 'selected' %}
                <li{% if activeClass %} class="{{ activeClass }}"{% endif %}>
                    <a href="{{ siteUrl ~ 'resources/'  ~ categorySlug ~ '/' ~ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endnav %}
        </ul>

    </div>
</aside>
```